# Check if contact submitted custom cloud page form in journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, cloudpage

I have a winback journey and want the contact to fill out a custom cloud page form. I want to steer them down different paths depending on if they have submitted the form or not.

I know i can check to see if they have clicked the link in the email that links to the page but want to check if they actually finish the form.

Is the best approach to put them in a data extension, link it in contact builder and use that as a decision split? Or is there any other approach?

Comment: yes you would need to use contact data in a decision split or exit criteria

Comment: I assume your form data gets saved somewhere, so if it’s landing in a Data Extension for example, you could use that DE in your decision split, just make sure to add it to your data model in Data Designer